# Laravel 5.1: Method "create" receiving a banch of data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that receives data from Person and Address. I want to save specific data in the Person table and in the Address table.

I'm using the method "create" from the Person model to persist first the Person, this method receives as parameter an array of data (related to Person and Address). So, I get an error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found ...", because it tries to insert Address value into Person table.

How to handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: My problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting either the $fillable or $guarded property on your Model's

for example, if your request contains the following data:

```
[ 
  'name' => 'Bill Mickelson',
  'street' => '123 Test Lane',
  'city' => 'Baltimore',
  'state' => 'Maryland'
]
```

and 'name' relates to Person, but the other 3 relate to Address you would do the following...

in Person.php:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name' ];
```

in Address.php:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'street', 'city', 'state' ];
```

After this, when you call create(), only the fields specified in $fillable will be populated.

As an aside, you can also just set $guarded to specify which SHOULDN'T be fillable, i.e. if each of these model's has an 'id' and you want everything else to be fillable, you can do:

```
protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a many-to-many relationship. I'm doing: `$person = PersonModel->create($data); ` and then `$person->address()->save($data); ` But I get "QueryException in Connection.php line 662:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row....."

Comment: The problem: I forgot to instantiate the address object. I did: `$person = PersonModel->create($data);`and then `$address= new Address($adrsData);` and then `$person->addresses()->create($address);` It saves the data in the Person table, Address table and PersonAddress table. But I have aditional fields in the PersonAddress table, such as the address_type and person_type. I tried to use the attach() method, but no sucess. Anyone know how to save data in the pivot table? Thanks.

Comment: The solution: `$person->address()->save($address, ['address_type' => '1', 'person_type' => '2']); ` It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `Person` model with `hasOne` or `hasMany` `Address`.

You shouldn't pass the address attributes in the `Person`'s create method. What you can do instead is first `create` the `Person`, then save an `Address` object related to that person.

For example:

```
$formData = ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 25, 'country' => 'US'];

$person = Person::create([
    'name' => $formData->name,
    'age' => $formdata->age
]);

$address = new Address([
    'name' => $formData->country
]);

// Save $address related to $person
// for ex. if Person hasOne Address:
$person->address()->save($address);
```

See [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) section in the docs.